# Give extra post-meta to RSS feeds

Tags: post-meta, rss, simplepie

I'm trying to extend an RSS feed to output some post-meta from my website.

I have an 'event_date' meta-key and I need to order by this as opposed to the RSS standard publish date, which I know how to do if I could get that information.

I'm using the following code, which makes use of the Wordpress action hooks available in the RSS feeds. However, when I use these hooks, the feeds report that there are no items found, while without these the items are found, but of course I cannot order them as I need.

Am I doing something wrong in the way that I am outputting to the RSS feed?

```
/**
 * Adds the 'event_date' meta value to a feed
 */
add_action('atom_entry', 'add_event_date_to_feed');
add_action('rdf_item', 'add_event_date_to_feed');
add_action('rss_item', 'add_event_date_to_feed');
add_action('rss2_item', 'add_event_date_to_feed');
function add_event_date_to_feed(){

    global $post;

    $event_date_raw = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', true);
    if($event_date_raw && $event_date_raw !== '') :
        $date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', $event_date_raw);
        $event_date = $date->format('U');
    else : 
        $event_date = '';
    endif;
    printf("\t\t".'<eventDate>%1$s</eventDate>'."\n", $event_date);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses SimplePie for *reading* feeds, not for generating feeds.  You're looking at two different things here:

1. You want to *output* your custom post meta in an RSS feed.
2. You want to read that custom post meta somewhere else.

The first part is pretty easy.  WordPress supports [custom RSS feed templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds).  You can actually replace the standard RSS feed with a custom one that includes your custom post meta.

As for *consuming* the custom data, that is pretty straight-forward.  SimplePie will read the RSS feed and create a feed object that includes everything that was in the XML file.  Just work with it like you would any other object.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I was not aware that SimplePie was only a reader. I have now amended all the templates for generating the output, but I understnad that there is a Cache Time for RSS that needs to expire before a new set of data is created, so I will wait patiently until that time to test these changes. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried a solution derived from you answer, but sadly it is causing my feeds to fail. I have now ammended my question to better reflect my original query, and I have added this problem. I'd be greatful for any further assistence that you can give. Thanks.